# In spite of my app is based 64 bit architecture, in ios 15 i am getting error message of "Apps need to be updated"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

"The developer of this app need to update its work with this version of ios".[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a matter of the architecture.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your architecture. It looks like your view or maybe an object called StickyGridCollectionViewFinal needs to be updated. I think your component is out dated perhaps.

Comment: If you've signed your app using an Enterprise certificate, then the solution is probably the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287653/4894980